# Selecting elements from an unknown numer of sets

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

I want to list all possible combinations that result from selecting at-least one and atmost all elements from each set out of a number(unknown) of sets input by user. An element may be in more than one set but listing it more than once is not a problem.

Eg:- If the user enters 3 sets as

```
{1,3,5}
{2,4}
{1}
```

Output

```
1,2,1
1,4,1
1,2,4,1
3,2,1
3,4,1
3,2,4,1
5,2,1
5,4,1
5,2,4,1
1,3,2,1
1,3,4,1
1,3,2,4,1
1,5,2,1
1,5,4,1
1,5,2,4,1
3,5,2,1
3,5,4,1
3,5,2,4,1
1,3,5,2,1
1,3,5,4,1
1,3,5,2,4,1
```

C# code will be even more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It looks as if you want the *cartesian product* of the *power sets* of your input sets, with the wrinkle that you are not interested in including the empty set which, formally, is a member of the power set of any set.  I have emphasised two terms, a search on SO will produce algorithms, probably also C# code, for these operations.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yours approach seems good

Comment: As a rep-whore I've turned my comment into an answer so that you can accept it -- and allow the rest of my peers either to admire my wisdom or chew on the bitter weeds of disappointment and downvote me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you want the *cartesian product* of the *power sets* of your input sets, with the wrinkle that you are not interested in including the empty set which, formally, is a member of the power set of any set. I have emphasised two terms, a search on SO will produce algorithms, probably also C# code, for these operations.

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this:
(a set do not contains duplicates)

```
def permutate(set_to_perm, perm):
    Boolean used; 

    for elemen_set_  in set_to_perm:
        used = false

        for element_perm in perm
             if element_set_ == element_perm:
                 used = true;
                 break;
        if used false:
           if lengh(set_to_perm) < lenght(perm)
               permutate(set_to_perm, append element_set_ to perm)
           else:
               print per

take input from user;
set_to_perm = make a set from user input;
permutate(set_to_perm,[]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all the sets you require with a recursive algorithm:

```
 current_set = { }

 enumerate (list_of_sets):
    if (list_of_sets is empty):
       REPORT current_set
    f = list_of_sets.front()
    r = list_of_sets.tail() /* all sets except f */
    n = f.size()
    for (i = 0 .. n - 1):
       current_set.insert(f[i])
       rec (f, i + 1, r)
       current_set.remove(f[i])

 rec (set, index, remaining_sets):
    if (index == set.size()):
       enumerate(remaining_sets)
    else:
       current_set.insert(f[index])
       rec(set, index + 1, remaining_sets)
       current_set.remove(f[index])
       rec(set, index + 1, remaining_sets)
```

Answer (score 0):

by F#

```
let rec comb n l =
  match n, l with
  | 0, _  -> [[]]
  | _, [] -> []
  | n, x::xs -> List.map (fun l -> x ::l) (comb (n - 1) xs) @ (comb n xs)

let powersets xs = seq {
    for i = 1 to List.length xs do
      for x in comb i xs -> x
  }

let rec powerset_out xs (acc:int list list) =
  if List.isEmpty xs then
    System.String.Join(",", seq { for el in acc do yield! el })
    |> printfn "%s"
  else
    let x::xs = xs
    for el in powersets x do
      powerset_out xs (acc @ [el])
```

Execution example:

```
> powerset_out [[1;3;5];[2;4];[1]] [];;
1,2,1
1,4,1
1,2,4,1
3,2,1
3,4,1
3,2,4,1
5,2,1
5,4,1
5,2,4,1
1,3,2,1
1,3,4,1
1,3,2,4,1
1,5,2,1
1,5,4,1
1,5,2,4,1
3,5,2,1
3,5,4,1
3,5,2,4,1
1,3,5,2,1
1,3,5,4,1
1,3,5,2,4,1
```